# Interview case with wrong information

Tags: interviewing

I am currently doing an interview case which needs to be submitted end of day tomorrow (public holiday). It is an analytical test with 10+ tables and the company provided an ER diagram.

The problem is, the ER diagram is not correct. Attributes are missing and there are also extra attributes. Worst is though that the 1:1 relationships are not correct, while it clearly stands in the description "X_ID is unique, Y_ID is unique" etc.

I don't think the incorrectness is part of the test, more than they have done several changes and then they sent it to me in a rush.

I won't be able to ask any questions tomorrow as it's a public holiday and I have already an interview scheduled on Wednesday.

I will continue doing the test, so I at least have something to present on Wednesday. Should I also reach out Tuesday and ask for a clarification after submitting the test?

Comment: What is "ER" ? What is an "analytical test" ?

Comment: @Hilmar Almost certainly an [entity-relationship diagram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93relationship_model).

Comment: Its a real life test.....

Comment: Giving incorrect and ambiguous information can be part of the test. It simulates real world work. If you throw your hands in the air and do nothing until the deadline as a result, it tells the employer everything they needed to know about you.

Comment: Someone is watching this and about to answer the "How the candidate deals with unclear requirements?" question in the interview feedback - "they have a high enough score on SO and Worplace.SE to ask anything and get an answer, no need to deal with uncertainty themselves" :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Correct obvious errors in the model and complete your work using the corrected version. When you submit the results, point out what exactly you have changed in the model and why.

However, be 100% sure they are errors and not something you may have misunderstood.

Comment: Or at least, explain that you _think_ they are errors and why - making a mistake in your analysis isn't terrible.

Comment: To expand on @PhilipKendall's comment, a good interviewer is going to be more interested in your thought process and openness to discussion than whether or not you simply got (what they think is) the correct answer. This is a good test simulating real-world conditions. How they respond to your answer tells you a lot about them and whether you actually want to work there or not.

Answer (score 6):

Welcome to the real world!

If they have given you an assessment task with ambiguous information, make the most sane assumptions, document them, and complete your task.

To increase your chances, and if it won't take too much additional effort, you could also make contrary assumptions, document them, and have an alternative completion of the task.

I would send them an email detailing the assumptions you will make, and ask them to let you know ASAP if they are not correct.